# Use excel to create dynamic range with Name and Hyperlink to that Name

Tags: excel, hyperlink, range, vba

I am trying to develop a quick and easy project management tracker.  I currently am using a inputbox to get the name of the project (PrjName) to add.  The code will then copy the template and paste it into the "Projects" worksheet at the next available COLUMN (+1 for extra space between projects).  I then want to add the PrjName as a list of projects on the dashboard worksheet but adding it as a hyperlink that will link to the appropriate column where the project has been pasted on the "Projects" worksheet.  I have figured out how to copy/paste the way I want it to look, but I don't know how to even start creating a reference for the hyperlink.  I thought I could possibly do this by using the project name to create a named range that somehow references the information pasted and then reference that name for the hyperlink but am not sure how to accomplish this.  Here is what I have for so far but it is probably a long way from correct.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim FirstBlankCol As Range

PrjName = InputBox("Enter the name of the project", "User Input Required")
If PrjName = "" Then Exit Sub

'Find First Blank Cell to add new Project on Summary Worksheet
Set FirstBlankCol = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Worksheets("Summary").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=FirstBlankCol, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
"PrjName", TextToDisplay:=PrjName

With Sheets("Projects")
    Select Case Sheets("Projects").Range("A1") = ""
        Case True 'paste in Col A if A1 is empty
            Sheets("Template").Range("A1:F5").Copy
            Sheets("Projects").Range("A1") _
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            Sheets("Projects").Range("A1") _
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
        Case False 'paste in next col
            Sheets("Template").Range("A1:F5").Copy
            Sheets("Projects").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 6) _
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            Sheets("Projects").Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 6) _
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
        End Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsPrj As Worksheet
    Dim wsTmp As Worksheet
    Dim rngDest As Range
    Dim strProjectName As String

    strProjectName = InputBox("Enter the name of the project", "User Input Required")
    If Len(Trim(strProjectName)) = 0 Then Exit Sub  'Pressed cancel

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set wsPrj = Sheets("Projects")
    Set wsTmp = Sheets("Template")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Len(wsPrj.Range("A1").Text) = 0 Then Set rngDest = wsPrj.Range("A1") Else Set rngDest = wsPrj.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 6)
    wsTmp.Range("A1:F5").Copy
    rngDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    rngDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Replace(strProjectName, " ", "_"), "='" & wsPrj.Name & "'!" & rngDest.Address
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1), "", Replace(strProjectName, " ", "_"), , strProjectName
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```